# Call directly without going to dialer

Tags: android

I want to call a number directly when clicking on a button.I want to call directly without going to dialer.when click on button i want to start the call immediatly.
I am currently using following code.Please help me.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", list.get(position).getMobile(), null)));
```

Answer (score 1):

you should add this permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

and also ask for permission in run time for android above 5

and change ACTION_DIAL to ACTION_CALL

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.fromParts("tel", list.get(position).getMobile(), null)));
```